# Git - Changes seen by the work copies, but not persisted in the Bare Repository

Tags: git, versioning

I and a couple of developers work locally on a server, we all connect there via RDP.

I've setup a folder in D:\Projects drive, to hold our bare repository.

All team members created local copies into their home folders and started working just fine, and by just fine I mean, every time someone commits and push the other can pull and see the changes.

But I'm intrigued with something, if I look into the bare repository, the files changed in there have not changed and keep their original content!!!

Is git storing the changes somewhere else?! If it is, how can I tell him to persist the changes directly over the bare repository files?!

Example: (jp user and cr user working)

- Before Push

  D:\Projects\fileA : content "ABC"

  D:\Versioning\jp\Projects\fileA : content "ABC D" -> changed

  D:\Versioning\cr\Projects\fileA : content "ABC" -> not seeing changes yet
- After Push from jp to repo and Pull from cr user

  D:\Projects\fileA : content "ABC" -> keeps the original

  D:\Versioning\jp\Projects\fileA : content "ABC D"

  D:\Versioning\cr\Projects\fileA : content "ABC D"

I'm checking repo files by right clicking them and edit with Notepad++.

At the beginning I created the repo with git init, then I realized that what I need was a bare, so I copied the contents of .git to the root of the repo, and modified the config to mark the repo as bare.

After, every developer cloned from this bare repo and now everything is going fine, except this little part, we need to have a place where the most up to date files are available to another team, responsible for the setups (for clients) creation.

Comment: How are you looking at the files in the "bare" repository?

Comment: @EdwardThomson right click, edit with Notepad++...

Comment: A *bare repository* does not contain a working directory. How are you accessing the files then? Sounds to me as if you don’t have a bare repository after all, but just use a normal repository as if it was bare. Operations on it won’t update the working directory though, which is why the changes won’t appear there.

Comment: @poke at the beginning i created the repo with git init, they i realized that what i need was a bare, so i copied the contents of .git to the root of the repo, and modified the config to mark the repo as bare. after every developer cloned from this bare repo and now everything is going fine, except this little part, we need to have a place where the most up to date files are available to another team, responsible for the setups creation.

Comment: The usual approach for that would be to set up a hook in the bare repository that “deploys” the current version to some other directory (or repository). I’m sure you can find some deployment hooks here on SO. You could for example do a work-tree checkout.

Comment: @poke Hum.. that seems interesting... so I can created a hook that performs a checkout to the same directory of my bare repo! Since, as we are discussing, the files in the repo are not used by git.

Comment: You could do that, yes. But if you want it at the same place, you could also just turn it into a non-bare repository again, set the `receive.denyCurrentBranch` configuration to `ignore` and then simply do a `git reset --hard master` as the hook’s action.

Comment: @poke :) Right! I've done that before, and I also set receive.denyCurrentBranch to ignore. But I didn't execute that second command of yours tough... And what happened was that, whenever I pushed changes... and then fetch, fetch tell me that the remote was updated, and when I performed pull to see what changed, my changes were lost... was like if my push had done nothing... Is that because I haven't done the git reset --hard master ???

Comment: @EdwardThomson can you comment about the proper way to update a bare repository? is it a good policy to perform a checkout of the bare repo via post-receive hook to extract the latest release of a project?

Comment: Hmm, no that doesn’t really sound right, but it’s difficult to tell what was going on there. But anyway, you do have multiple options to do deployment (which is essentially what you are looking for). So just search for some deployment strategies and see what works best for you.

Comment: @poke Yes you are probably right, I just found this after your answer http://chilipepperdesign.com/2013/01/07/deploying-code-with-git/, later on, I'll update this with my findings. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bare repositories don't contain a working tree they contain the state of the `.git`-folder of non-bare repositories. You cannot directly see the files that are stored inside them.

In case your bare repository is not a real bare repository: Pushing into a normal repository does not update the working tree and pushing into a non-bare repository is not recommended.

In case you were looking at the objects folder: Files in the objects folder are immutable and won't get modified. They will only be deleted and added.

**Note:** You should not modify the contents of a bare repository unless you really really know what you are doing, as this may destroy the repository. The bare repository is meant to be managed by git itself.

Comment: My objective is, the developers here are working frenetically on their working copies, and sometimes they need to generate and executable file with the code. After doing that they just, push the changes upstream. The idea here is to tell your manager something like, hey the executable is available at d:/repo/myprogram/myprogram.exe .

Comment: @JoãoPinho git is bad a storing binary data. Those executables should rather be shown on the developer's machine or put onto an USB drive or put into some internal network storage. But git certainly is not the right tool for it.

Comment: I understand Tim... but considering my updated question, even if modify a text file, the repo doesn't show the changes, even though my colleagues can pull and see them...

Comment: @JoãoPinho I have no idea in what state your repository is by now, but in order to have an up to date copy you can use the post-receive hook to pull into another working copy.

Comment: Ok that is similar to what poke suggested just now, so I can created a lets say "latest-release" working copy, and then pull to there. But my question is, is this a good practice, I would like to see some guides about how is this scenario typically addressed.

Comment: @JoãoPinho I don't think do's and don'ts should be discussed in the comments and I never needed those hooks by myself as I am using GitHub for these kind of things.

Comment: If I could use GitHub I would be much happier... But thanks anyway.